# Creating an extension to PyDev

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I would like to create an extension to PyDev. I want that this extension download some python files in some shared folder and download it to the project's folder. Also want that anytime the file is saved it is uploaded to this shared folder.

I can't manage to get PyDev extension points to work. Anyone has an example of something similar?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I partially got it.
It's needed to add an extension referencing the org.python.pydev.pydev_pyedit_listener
we then associate to this listener a class

```
public class MyPyEditListener implements IPyEditListener, IPyEditListener3{}
```

in this class we will have the following method:

```
@Override
public void onSave(BaseEditor arg0, IProgressMonitor arg1) {

    System.console().writer().println("=== YaY:  onSave");
}
```

Now I only need a extension to get the right python files according to the imports found in some file... Need to look, looking good :D